# SVG does not display in img tag in Safari

Tags: html, css, svg, safari

Simply put, I have an SVG graphic embedded in HTML that refuses to display in Safari (although it works fine in Chrome, Firefox, and other browsers).

I'm using the following markup to accomplish this:

```
<img alt="grapefruit logo" src="/assets/better-gf-logo_red.svg" />
```

Here is a live link to the the page where the SVG is not displaying. The fruit logo in the top left corner does not display in Safari: https://grapefruit.cs.rpi.edu/.

I have verified the following line is also present in my nginx `mime.types`:

```
 image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
```

However, I know that the issue is probably not related to mime types, since the SVG doesn't appear in Safari on my development machine either (I tested several web servers). I have also tried displaying the [SVG file itself](https://grapefruit.cs.rpi.edu/assets/better-gf-logo_red-695bceb330554b7b70ffefc99bb7a858.svg) in Safari, and it looks fine. The image element has the right size and box model, but it is not displaying any content.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turns out that `<img src="image.svg">` will not work in Safari, I tried using `<object>` and it worked. Give this a try: **[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/poyagu/2/edit)**

```
<object
   type="image/svg+xml"
   height="70"
   width="150"
   data="/assets/better-gf-logo_red.svg">
</object>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object

Comment: Thanks so much! I had no idea Safari had issues with the `<img>` tag being used for SVGs, there isn't much documentation online.

Comment: @autibyte take a look at Meuwka's answer

Comment: I'm wondering if the PNG contents of the svg might be the real cause of  the problem in Safari. Does the other svg image in the example by @meuwka http://jsbin.com/kayiwe/ work in Safari?

Comment: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=118068 seems data uris aren't supported inside svg content.

Comment: That solved my problems too but still wondering why safari did not display my png convert to SVG. I am going to try to save original ai file as svg, let see how it turns out.

Comment: @orko it makes no sense to use the png inside svg in this case.  You can use it as png - it will be the same. If you save a bitmap image as svg, then it will not be a vector! not scalable (as vector) http://cl.ly/Y5ue and has large size http://cl.ly/Y5Tn You can convert to vector with Image Trace in Illustrator or by other methods

Comment: @meuwka yo are 100% right I know that it is not going to a vector file.  I just want to give it a try, just wanted to start to use SVG files for responsive templates and it was a start up.

Comment: Best answer so far! Thanks

Comment: IMG + SVG as src worked on mobile safari until I added style='width:100px', but switching to Object tag w/ data instead of source worked <object style="width: 154px;" data="/Content/img/logo/XXXX.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>

Answer (score 2):

First of all your image is not SVG
you can open it in a text editor and see - it's PNG (not vector) only saved as SVG

```
... width="1640" height="422" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgA...
```

check here http://jsbin.com/kayiwe/